# JS SQLite select sum where not equal

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I use the code below in order to get the sum from columns score_h and score_a whithout the line where point_id = 'set'

```
db.transaction(function(t) {
    t.executeSql('SELECT SUM(score_h) AS myscore_h, SUM(score_a) AS myscore_a FROM playerstats WHERE matchid = ? AND point_id <> ?', [globalmatchid, 'set']);
});
```

but the result does not exclude the point_id lines that are not equal to 'set'

Where am i Wrong?

Comment: Are you sure? Run the query directly without the SUMs and check the rows you get. If they are excluded there they will be excluded from the aggregations as well.

Comment: Watch out for `null` values: `WHERE matchid = ? AND (point_id IS NULL OR point_id <> ?)`.